# Can't get clojure to work in eclipse; must set system property clojure.compile.path, must also be on your classpath

Tags: eclipse, clojure

I've been fighting with Eclipse for a couple hours now and had to fall back to JRE 1.8 to get it to work. I can now get it to start a REPL except when I hit the green "play" button (when, on mouseover, it says "run core.clj") but then when I hit it again (for when it's on "run compile"), it says this:

ERROR: Must set system property clojure.compile.path
to the location for compiled .class files.
This directory must also be on your CLASSPATH.

What is this telling me to do, and how do I actually set this system property?

And what do I name it in my classpath variables?

Thanks and sorry if this is overly simple; I've just spent way too much time on this.

Edit: Yes, I'm using counterclockwise

Comment: Are you using couterclockwise plugin? You can add the `clojure.compile.path` system property under run configuration to where the clojure files are compiled. Usually to target or bin (depends).

Comment: Can recommend trying IntelliJ with [Cursive](https://cursive-ide.com/) plugin works without any problems